# Render objects based on zoom level in Azure indoor maps

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Is there a way to show/hide objects on a map based on the zoom level in azure indoor maps module? Honestly, I'm not so sure if this feature even exist yet

Answer (score 2):

Custom styling of indoor maps in Azure Maps is a planned feature.

Note that indoor maps leverage vector tiles for rendering and items that don't appear when zoomed out, are not loaded in the map, so you won't be able to show things that aren't there at this time. There will likely be some configuration for this in the future. Things that do appear today could potentially be hidden although in a bit of a hacky way since this custom styling of indoor maps isn't officially supported yet.

For example, using the building from the indoor maps tutorial, the following sets the zoom level range of the room number labels to 0 - 22.

```
map.map.setLayerZoomRange("indoor_global_unit_label", 0, 22)
```

The first value in that function is the id of the rendering layer which I retrieved by running the following code in the console, then moving the mouse over the item I wanted to get the id for:

```
map.events.add('mousemove', function (e) { console.log(e.shapes[0].layer.id ) })
```

The second and third parameter of the setLayerZoomRange method is the min and max zoom levels. When that line of code is ran, you will notice the labels appear when zoomed out much longer than usual, however, if you zoom out enough, they disappear since they become no longer available in the vector tiles.